# So what's the purpose of Borel algebras?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

I am currently working my way through probability theory, and stumbled upon a number of instances in which Borel sets/algebras/measures were specified (usually with Lebesgue integrals mentioned). So far I could not find out what exactly is to be gained from specifying you are working on a Borel set. My understanding is probably flawed, so I'd just write down what I've understood so far, and hope you could point out where I went wrong, or what I am missing.
Here's what I have gathered so far:

$$\{ \mbox{Borel sets} \} \subseteq\{ \mbox{Borel algebra} \} \subseteq \{ \mbox{Sigma algebra} \} $$

**Borel sets** seem to be a special kind of sigma algebra, created from every single combination you can get from unions, intersections and complements on closed and open intervals. **Borel algebras** are a collection of borel sets, on which Borel measures are defined - I assume the need to make the distinction between sets and algebra arises from the fact that you can choose subsets of the Borel algebra and work with these. Apparently Borel sets are **not** power sets, although I still fail to see why.

**Now the main point**: Particularly in probability theory, what is to be gained from specifying that you are working on a Borel algebra over specifying you are in a sigma algebra? What is the information carried by this distinction?

Comment: 1. Borel measures are compatible with the underlying topology in an appropriate sense, which is important in certain situations. 2. In probability theory we frequently find ourselves wanting to compose random variables. When you do this, because the definition of Lebesgue measurability of a function is not symmetric with respect to the $\sigma$-algebras involved, the function composed "on the left" must be Borel measurable to ensure the composition is Lebesgue measurable. 3. I can say more if you're a bit more concrete about where this is used.

Comment: @Ian: Wow, quick answer! One context in which I've stumbled over this was for example from a paper on sequential Markov models: there they specify a sequence of transition kernels $\tau:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow[0,1]$ where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is n-dimensional real space.

Comment: That could probably be the Lebesgue measurable sets if I'm not missing something. Of course sometimes it really doesn't matter.